# Disabling logger in Flask Socket.io

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

I have an application using Flask and FlaskSocket.IO 2.8.4. When I initialise SocketIO, I am using

```
#[...]

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,format='[%(asctime)s][%(levelname)s] - %(funcName)s: %(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
handler = logging.FileHandler(__builtin__.config['dir']['log_file_handler'])
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s][%(levelname)s] - %(funcName)s: %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)

# Setting up flask external plugins
socketio = SocketIO(app, logger = False)

#[...]

if __name__ == '__main__':
socketio.run(app, port=8000)
```

Anyway, the output in my log has a lot of `emit`, `receive` and `handle_event` lines:

```
[2017-04-19 05:17:02,172][INFO] - receive: 1139f764dbe64a1ba6e1c8d95228400c: Received packet MESSAGE data 2/telescope,["AskForTimeEvent"]
[2017-04-19 05:17:02,173][INFO] - _handle_event: received event "AskForTimeEvent" from 1139f764dbe64a1ba6e1c8d95228400c [/telescope]
[2017-04-19 05:17:02,173][INFO] - emit: emitting event "clockEvent" to all [/telescope]
[2017-04-19 05:17:02,174][INFO] - send: 1139f764dbe64a1ba6e1c8d95228400c: Sending packet MESSAGE data 2/telescope,["clockEvent",{"hr":5,"sec":2,"min":17}]
[2017-04-19 05:17:03,287][INFO] - receive: 1139f764dbe64a1ba6e1c8d95228400c: Received packet MESSAGE data 2/telescope,["AskForTimeEvent"]
[2017-04-19 05:17:03,287][INFO] - _handle_event: received event "AskForTimeEvent" from 1139f764dbe64a1ba6e1c8d95228400c [/telescope]
[2017-04-19 05:17:03,288][INFO] - emit: emitting event "clockEvent" to all [/telescope]
[2017-04-19 05:17:03,288][INFO] - send: 1139f764dbe64a1ba6e1c8d95228400c: Sending packet MESSAGE data 2/telescope,["clockEvent",{"hr":5,"sec":3,"min":17}]
```

I am using the `emit` function this way:

```
# this inside a function of an arbitrary class, works fine, but writes a lot of log!
with self.app.test_request_context('/telescope'):
        self.socketio.emit('someEvent', json.dumps(arr), namespace='/telescope')
```

I would think that the argument `logger=False` when instantiating the `SocketIO` object prevents these big repetitive messages, but it doesn't. I would be very thankful if someone can help me with this.

S.

Added info: I already tried with the option `log_output=False` when `socketio.run`, but the result is exactly the same.

Comment: what is version of `socket-io`? because there is a bug wiht logging in version `0.8.6 `. Or Try you with `engineio_logge=False`.

Comment: I checked and `python-socketio==1.7.1` and `python-engineio==1.2.3`. I tried your `engineio_logger=False` both in SocketIO object instantiation and `socketio.run` but didn't work.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The reason the logging changes you are applying don't work is that the global changes you've applied via `logging.basicConfig` take precedence.

Here is how you can override those defaults, just for the Socket.IO logger:

```
logging.getLogger('socketio').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logging.getLogger('engineio').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

This will set both packages to log only errors.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks again Miguel :)

Comment: I had to add: logging.getLogger('geventwebsocket.handler').setLevel(logging.ERROR) after the module started working in order for it to work